# Control-M How do I remove a portion of the filename during Advanced File Transfer

Tags: control-m

I am trying to figure out how I can simply remove a portion of a filename on a transfer. I need the numbers to remain unchanged with 'check-aft' buttressing up against them as a prefix.

Source: check-aft-eft-12345678-0001
Destination: check-aft12345678-0001

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to either use the Find and Replace feature which BMC mentions, but then provides zero guidance for, or how I would utilize the variables to do so. I have review all of their documentation and watched so many videos, but they do not cover this scenario.

I would appreciate any help getting '-eft-' removed from this filename.

I have tried creating variables for '-eft-' and for 'check-aft' but I am unable to figure out how i can tell it to look for 'check-aft-eft-' and remove '-eft-'

Answer (score 0):

Find & Replace is used for making bulk changes to job definitions, it has no direct relation to AFT jobs (unless you are changing the AFT job defs, that is).

The AFT jobs have many useful features hidden away on the "Advanced" button. If you literally want to change the file name, click Advanced and go to "Destination Actions" on the General tab. Here select "Renamed" where it says "After the completion of a successful file transfer the destination file will be:" and enter check-aft12345678-0001.

If, however, the numbers can be any value - go to the "File Watcher" tab (still in the "Advanced" pop-up) and use "Output / Variable containing detected file name". Set it to something like found_aft_file_1.

You now have a variable that you can do SUBSTR on -

%%PARTONE = %%SUBSTR %%found_aft_file_1 1 10
%%PARTTWO = %%SUBSTR %%found_aft_file_1 15 13

Then %%PARTONE.%%PARTTWO will return the required value.

Comment: Sorry, the %%PARTONE & %%PARTTWO variables should be on different lines.

Comment: Thank you kind sir! I will attempt this today.